# Get last month and year in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This table like this

```
| id | months | years |
-----------------------
| 1  | 12     | 2019  |
| 2  | 1      | 2020  |
| 3  | 2      | 2020  |
| 4  | 3      | 2020  |
```

I want to query last month assume if months = 1 and years = 2020 it will get row id = 1, months = 12, years = 2019. I tried to write like this

```
select *
from dates
where months = case months - 1
                  when 0
                      then 12
                  else months - 1
                end
and years = case months - 1
                  when 0
                      then years - 1
                  else years
                end
and months = 2
and years = 2020
```

but, this doesn't work

how do I write sql? thanks.

Comment: Can you explain where you get the value of months? Or try explaining a little more to clarify your situation.

Comment: I want to compare data between month by receive argument and last month if month by receive argument is 1 last month must be 12

Answer (score 3):

You can use `year() & month()`

```
WHERE years = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
      months = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```